# How to convert Firebase Old Adapter method to New Adapter method?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

In the main Screen of my app I was trying to build a Search View with Edit Text. I have made a recycler view below the search view. My app is a music app. So I want to build a function like when user search any song from firebase then the song name and song artist should be displayed in the recycler view. So i have read a code for do this particular work. But I am facing a problem like In my code there was a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter method which was used to get values from firebase from my search view ,  but my problem is it was old `populateViewHolder` method and I want to convert this method to new on `createView` and `onBindViewHolderMethod` but i don't know how? So please help me to change this method and I want to do same Search View work. I don't want to change my Firebase Dependencies in my gradle. So finally conclusion is I want to convert the code which was given below to new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter method.

Here is my code :-

```
 Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("name").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(

                Users.class,
                R.layout.list_layout,
                UsersViewHolder.class,
                firebaseSearchQuery

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {


                viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getName(), model.getStatus(), model.getImage());

            }
        };

        mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

So please help me if you have any solution.

Comment: You are using a very old version of the Firebase-UI library. You should use the latest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter) shows, you first initialize a `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` object with the query and class:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users>()
                .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery, Users.class)
                .build();
```

And you then create a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` with that `options` object and your `ViewHolder` class:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    public ChatHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);

        return new UsersViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(UsersViewHolder holder, int position, Users model) {
        viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getName(), model.getStatus(), model.getImage());
    }
};
mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

And then you [call `startListening()` and `stopListening()` in the relevant activity lifecycle events](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#startstop-listening).

Comment: I tried your code but it is not loading data from firebase