# Not Getting Data From Firebase Realtime DataBase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I was making an app and In my main Screen I have an Edit Text and a RecyclerView which was fixed below the Edit Text. and I have a Search Button also in the screen. I want to make a Funcion like when user Enter some value in Edit Text and after adding the value when user clicks the Search Button then it retrieves the value from Firebase and Show in the Recycler View. It means I want to make a Search View with Firebase. So, I have written a code for it but the problem is I am not getting value from Firebase. When I clicks the search button then my recycler view remains blank.

I have provided my code below and I want to make complete Search view.

Here is my code :-

```
public class SearchFactorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mSearchField;
    private ImageButton mSearchBtn;

    private RecyclerView mResultList;

    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firebase_main_activity);

        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");


        mSearchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_field);
        mSearchBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search_btn);

        mResultList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.result_list);
        mResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String searchText = mSearchField.getText().toString();

                firebaseUserSearch(searchText);

            }
        });

    }

    private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {

        Query firebaseSearchQuery  = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("name").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "/uf8ff");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users>().setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery ,Users.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users , UsersViewHolder>(options) {

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_layout , parent , false);
                return new UsersViewHolder(v);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder usersViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Users users) {

                usersViewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext() , users.getName()  , users.getStatus() , users.getImage());

            }
        };

        mResultList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    // View Holder Class

    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void setDetails(Context ctx, String userName, String userStatus, String userImage){

            TextView user_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
            TextView user_status = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
            ImageView user_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);


            user_name.setText(userName);
            user_status.setText(userStatus);

            Glide.with(ctx).load(userImage).into(user_image);


        }




    }

}
```

Here is my Modal class :-

```
public class Users {

    public String name, image, status;

    public Users(){

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Users(String name, String image, String status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

My Firebase Structure :-

[image]

So please help me If you have any solution.

Comment: Can you add your database structure ?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Ok Sir Please Wait

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added please seee

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I have added please see

Comment: Note that I explicitly told you to call `startListening` in my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825571/how-to-convert-firebase-old-adapter-method-to-new-adapter-method). :-/